# binomial distribution interpretation

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, mode

I am working on a binomial distribution problem, where I would like to calculate the probability of observing 48601000 successes in 69430000 trials, where the success probability is $p = 0.70$. I compute this using the binomial pmf:
$$\binom{69430000}{48601000} 0.70^{48601000} (0.30)^{20829000} \approx 0.0001044785$$
Can anyone provide some intuition as to why this probability is so low, given that $p = 0.70$? Just trying to wrap my head around it!

Comment: It might be more revealing to invert your question: could you tell us why we should expect the probability of any particular number of successes to be so *high*, given that there are almost 70 million trials and therefore even more possibilities for the number of successes?

Comment: Hi. That is a good point. I suppose in some sense there is nothing "special" about a particular number of successes.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you surprised? The number of possible outcomes is very large, all with some positive probability, so the individual probabilities cannot be too large. We can calculate the *maximum possible point probability* for your specific binomial distribution, with some help from R:

```
n <- 69430000
p <- 0.7
max(dbinom(c((n+1)*p, (n+1)*p-1), n, p))
    0.0001044785
```

which is what you have given, because the number of successes you gave is the mode of that particular binomial distribution.